# ASP.NET Core MVC. Неправильная переадресация при выполнении метода действия

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, razor

Я только изучаю ASP.NET, поэтому вопрос, возможно, глупый. Как я понимаю, ошибка не в коде, а в понимании того как работает платформа. Непонятно что именно не работает так, как я того ожидаю, поэтому опишу ситуацию целиком.

Есть контроллер OrderController управляющий заказами в приложении. В нём есть метод List() извлекающий список неотправленных заказов из БД и возвращающий ответом страницу представляющую этот список. В таблице со списком для каждого заказа создаётся кнопка "Ship", вызывающая метод MarkShipped(int) с ID заказа в качестве параметра. Метод MarkShipped(int) помечает необходимый заказ как отправленный и производит переадресацию на метод List().

Итого, что должно происходить: браузер получил страницу со списком заказов, пользователь нажал на одном из элементов списка кнопку "Ship", страница обновилась, указанного элемента в списке нет.

И что происходит по факту: при переходе по адресу "localhost/Order/List/" браузер получает страницу со списком заказов, при нажатии на кнопку вызывается метод MarkShipped(int), заказ помечается как отправленный, и далее происходит перенаправление на метод List(). Но при этом переадресация происходит не на адрес "localhost/Order/List/", а на "localhost/Order/" с ответом в виде пустой страницы.

Вот код контроллера OrderController.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SportsStore.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace SportsStore.Controllers
{
    public class Ordercontroller : Controller
    {
        private IOrderRepository repository;
        private Cart cart;

        public Ordercontroller(IOrderRepository repoService, Cart cartService)
        {
            repository = repoService;
            cart = cartService;
        }
        public ViewResult List() =>
            View(repository.Orders.Where(о => !о.Shipped));
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult MarkShipped(int orderID)
        {
            Order order = repository.Orders
                .FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderID == orderID);
            if (order != null)
            {
                order.Shipped = true;
                repository.SaveOrder(order);
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(List));
        }

        //...

    }
}
```

Как я понял, оно перестаёт работать в строке

```
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(List));
```

При отладке выяснилось, что выполнения метода List() после этого не происходит.

И вот текст представления List.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Order>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Orders";
    Layout = "_AdminLayout";
}

<div class="container">
    @if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th><th>Zip</th><th colspan="2">Details</th><th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (Order o in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@o.Name</td>
                        <td>@o.Zip</td>
                        <td>Product</td>
                        <td>Quantity</td>
                        <td>
                            <form asp-action="MarkShipped"
                                  method="post">
                                <input type="hidden"
                                       name="orderId"
                                       value="@o.OrderID" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                                    Ship
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (CartLine l in o.Lines)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"></td>
                            <td>@l.Product.Name</td>
                            <td>@l.Quantity</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="text-center">
            <p>No unshipped orders!</p>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Буду очень  рад получить ответ на свой вопрос, или название того, незнание чего приводит к этой ошибке)

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Метод ненаучного тыка позволил мне найти решение:

Замена вызова метода RedirectToAction(nameof(List)) на метод Redirect(nameof(List)) в методе MarkShipped(int) приводит к тому, что всё начинает работать как предполагается.

Но понятнее от этого не становится:

1. Прочтённая мной документация говорит, что метод Redirect должен принимать полный URL-адрес перенаправления. В нашем же случае передаётся только строка "List".
2. В приложении есть почти идентичный контроллер в котором метод RedirectToAction() работает как надо. Возвращаемые типы и схема переадресации там идентичные.
3. Почему оно стало работать?

Буду очень благодарен, если кто то объяснит мне почему так происходит.